# Fix index column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following data (output from Jupyter Notebook)

[image]

Is there anyway I can name the first column?  I can't access it because it seems like its a row name column.

Or otherwise extract the first unamed column and make a new dataframe with ['accessions'] and ['symbols']

Comment: I think that the first column is an index. you can set the name of the index by df.index.name = 'myindex'

Comment: How are you creating this dataframe ? Looks like you don't want first column to become index rather you want that as a separate column and there are ways to do it but solution depends on how you create dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`pd.DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

That is the index...
Using @JesseVogt's sample dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
         'asc': [['XM', 'NM', 'XM'], ['NM', 'XM'], ['NM', 'NM', 'NM'], ['NM']],
         'sym': [{'CP', 'BT', 'MF'}, {'BC', 'CP'}, {'NT', 'IF', 'NT5'}, {'BA'}],
     },
    index=[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'G'), ('A', 'U')]
)
```

You can rename the index and have it appear above the index when displayed

```
df.rename_axis('MyName')

                 asc            sym
MyName                             
(A, A)  [XM, NM, XM]   {MF, BT, CP}
(A, C)      [NM, XM]       {BC, CP}
(A, G)  [NM, NM, NM]  {NT, IF, NT5}
(A, U)          [NM]           {BA}
```

Or you can reset the index to place that information into the dataframe proper

```
df.rename_axis('MyName').reset_index()

   MyName           asc            sym
0  (A, A)  [XM, NM, XM]   {MF, BT, CP}
1  (A, C)      [NM, XM]       {BC, CP}
2  (A, G)  [NM, NM, NM]  {NT, IF, NT5}
3  (A, U)          [NM]           {BA}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only given that DataFrame and can't change how it is constructed you can call [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) to extract the index into a column:

```
In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    ...:     'asc': [['XM', 'NM', 'XM'], ['NM', 'XM'], ['NM', 'NM', 'NM'], ['NM']],
    ...:     'sym': [{'CP', 'BT', 'MF'}, {'BC', 'CP'}, {'NT', 'IF', 'NT5'}, {'BA'}],
    ...: }, index=[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'G'), ('A', 'U')])

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
                 asc            sym
(A, A)  [XM, NM, XM]   {BT, CP, MF}
(A, C)      [NM, XM]       {CP, BC}
(A, G)  [NM, NM, NM]  {NT, NT5, IF}
(A, U)          [NM]           {BA}

In [15]: df.reset_index(drop=False)
Out[15]:
    index           asc            sym
0  (A, A)  [XM, NM, XM]   {BT, CP, MF}
1  (A, C)      [NM, XM]       {CP, BC}
2  (A, G)  [NM, NM, NM]  {NT, NT5, IF}
3  (A, U)          [NM]           {BA}
```

To remove that index entirely you would use `drop=True`. The name can be changed by first naming the index with `df.index.name = 'some_name'`.